# Why they differ in html and css? id inside vs outside video tag

Tags: css, html

I want to make a video as a background of whole browser. I tried two different ways. as the code showed below, I set up the id between  in css to # backgroundvideo, there is always some blank space left in the right and button side. The second one is to set up #video outside, it works well except for not responsive. Why they differ?

The html code:

```
<div id ="video"><video id ="backgroundvideo" autoplay loop="true">
      <source src="videos/test2.mp4" loop="true">
  </video> 
  </div>
```

The css code:

```
 #backgroundvideo{
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

or

```
#video{
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

Plus: how to make the videos static even the browser is resized? since both of the way i mentioned will make the video size change when resizing browser.

Comment: Need some screenshots or running code to see what you mean

Comment: Use specific dimensions to make them static rather than percentages.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div id ="video">
<video id ="backgroundvideo" autoplay loop="true" width="100%" height="100%">
    <source src="videos/test2.mp4" loop="true"/>
</video> 
</div>
```

css

```
#backgroundvideo{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%    !important;
    height: auto   !important;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

i put code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/DjdCM/

for more information, check this:

http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: Thanks Lance! I've tried but the video background still change when I move browser, it works on yours?